# What is the inner difference between (MyType)SomeObj.Property1 and (MyType)(SomeObj.Property1) in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, properties

It's probably very lame question, but I found no references in C# specification about round brackets. Please point me to spec or msdn if answer on that question will be obvious.

What is the inner difference between (MyType)SomeObj.Property1 and (MyType)(SomeObj.Property1) in C# ?

AFAIK, in first case ( (x)SomeObj.Property1 cast ) - it will be the reference of concrete type (MyType) to Property1. In second case, such reference will execute get accessor SomeObj.get_Property1. 
And it eventually could lead to subtle errors if get accessor have any side effects (and its often - do have ones)

Could anyone point me to exact documentation where such behaviour specified ?

Updated: Thank you for pointing. And I deeply apologize about such dumb question - after posting this question, I found a typo in example I fiddle with and thus realized that second case behaviour was not based on code I tried to compile, but on previously compiled completely different code. So my question was initially based on my own blindness ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent.  This is determined by the operator precedence rules in the C# language, chapter 7.2.1 in the C# Language Specification:

[image]

The `.` operator is at the top in this list, the cast operator is the 2nd in the list.  The `.` operator "wins".  You will have use parentheses if you need the cast because *Property1* is a property of the MyType class:

```
 ((MyType)SomeObj).Property1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference. The `.` operator binds more tightly than the typecast operator, so the extra parentheses make no difference. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28VS.71%29.aspx) for details of operator precedence; the operators in question are in the first two groups.