# How do you determine the actual type of a ToolStripItem in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a VB.Net application to C#. Everything else is going great. Except this bit. I have a function which builds menus,sub menus and seperators from a database. It can build a MenuStrip or a ContextMenuStrip which can then be assigned to a form.

This means that menus can be extensive and conpmex but managed outside the application, which I also use as part of my security access model. All menus are controlled from the database externally, it also means I can develop visual tools (Treeviews etc) to manage user menus. The application uses menus extensively which is by design.

Programmatically I want to assign an eventhandler to every item that isnt a dropdown or a seperator

In VB I would do this, (works perfectly)

```
Private Sub AddHandlers (ByVal voMenuItems As ToolStripItemCollection)

For Each oItem in voMenuItems
    If TypeOf(oItem) is ToolStripDropDown then
        if oItem.DropDownItems.Count > 0 then
            AddHandlers(oItem.DropDownItems)
        Else
            AddHandler oItem.Click, AddressOf ToolBarButtonClick
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub

Private Sub ToolbarButtonClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

'Do something

End Sub
```

but how would I achieve the same in C#

I have to code my loop like this

```
foreach (ToolStripItem oItem in voMenuItems)
```

Which always returns a ToolStripItem (using either, GetType or typeof), I cannot find any way to determine the type of item (ToolStripDropDown or ToolStripSeperator) that the ToolStripItem actually is, and even then I can't cast to the type that I want e.g.

```
(ToolStripDropDown)oItem.DropDownItems.Count ...
```

This gives a compile time error

"System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownItems' and no extension method 'DropDownItems' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: The cast doesn't work due to operator precedence rules, the dot operator is 'stronger' than the cast operator.  Parentheses required: ((ToolStripDropDown)oItem).DropDownItems.Count.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022377/what-is-the-inner-difference-between-mytypesomeobj-property1-and-mytypesomeo/4022427#4022427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways:

```
ToolStripDropDown tsdd = oItem as ToolStripDropDown
if (tsdd != null)
{
}
```

The 'as' cast will return null if it doesn't work, or you can do:

```
try
{
    ToolStripDropDown tsdd = (ToolStripDropDown)oItem;
}
catch
{
    // Do something ...
}
```

Also to check a type of an object do:

```
bool isToolStripDropDown = oItem is ToolStripDropDown;
```

or:

```
bool isToolStripDropDown = oItem.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripDropDown);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the foreach mentioning an Object type or an anonymous type like this:

`foreach (object oItem in voMenuItems)
...
if(typeof(oItem) == ... )
...`

or 

`foreach(var oItem in voMenuItems)
...`

In case the typeof doesn't return the type you wish you can try and to the cast using the 'as' and checking if the returned object is null

`if(oItem as ToolstripDropDown != null)
....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword.

So,

`If TypeOf(oItem) is ToolStripDropDown` (VB)

becomes

`if (oItem is ToolStripDropDown)` (C#)

You might also want to look at the [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword, which allows you to attempt to cast to a type but returns null if the conversion's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In VB I was able to do

```vb
oItem.GetType.ToString
```

So in this code:

```vb
                    Dim tmenu As New ToolStripMenuItem(menu.Name)
                    ASRMenus.DropDownItems.Insert(mPosition, tmenu)
                    Dim t As ToolStripItem = CType(tmenu, ToolStripItem)
```

asking this in the debugger

```
?t.GetType.tostring
```

gave "System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem"